# AWS Config rules with no resources by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-systems-manager

I have an AWS Config rule set up to look for the 'Certify The Web' application using the `EC2_MANAGEDINSTANCE_APPLICATIONS_REQUIRED` rule. I have the scope of resources to a tag Key of `ACM` and value of `Managed`, so any server with this tag should have the application installed.

[image: Rule trigger]

However, this rule never returns any results because it says nothing is in scope. I have 6 instances with this tag, for example:
[image]

Re-evaluating the rule never returns results. If I change it to all managed instances, it will work but I get a bunch of non-compliant resources because there are some servers that won't have it installed. Am I using the tag functionality wrong, or am I misunderstanding something?